# How do i make a custom endpoint via router in Express for Socket.IO?

Tags: node.js, json, express, socket.io

I'm currently trying to make an app, my backend is in express, and my frontend in React Native, so basically i want to listen from changes on some other process, and whenever it changes, send it via socket to the client (React frontend) can execute changes depending on what the server sends, but for some reason whenever i try to make a petition to my endpoint `/api/gameflow/status` returns nothing or `socket hang up` (Using Postman), and on a custom script in python the response is `Empty`

I'm trying to use a router to organize my code, so the endpoint is placed in the `gameflow.js`
file, i also tried changing the `foo.listen(PORT)` (foo) to both app and http, while using `app` the `console.log()` stops working for some reason.

`index.js`

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const http = require("http").Server(app)
const io = require("socket.io")(http)

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080

const gameflow = require("./modules/gameflow")

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.io = io
    next();
})

app.use("/api/gameflow", gameflow)

http.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`[SERVER] Opening backend @ port ${PORT}`)
    lcu_hook.riot_cert();
})
```

`/modules/gameflow.js`

```
const router = require("express").Router()
const { response } = require("express")

router.use(async (req, res, next) => {
    //check if process is running
    /*
    !!! REPLACED JUST FOR SECURITY, THIS IS THE EXACT SAME STRUCTURE ON THE ORIGINAL FILE !!!
    if (process is running) {
        next()
    } else {
        res.json({ "error": "APP_NOT_OPEN" })
        next()
    }
    */
})

router.get('/status', (req, res) => {
    req.io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        socket.emit("Connected to server")
        console.log('user connected'); socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            console.log('user disconnected');
        });
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically i had a problem with async process handling, but to make a custom endpoint using a router you must have a main `Express` server and a `router` on another file

`server.js`

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const http = require("http").Server(app)

/* THIS IS GOING TO BE THE PREFIX FOR THE ROUTER */
app.use("/my/custom/endpoint", require("router.js"));
```

`router.js`

```
const router = require("express").Router()
const { response } = require("express")

router.get("/msg", (req,res) => {
    res.json({message:"Hello world"})
}
```

So, when you visit `http://localhost/my/custom/endpoint/msg` it should return `{message:"Hello world"}`